# Problem with the pst-geo bundle

Tags: pstricks

I have tried to compile the code in this example from [Political map in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13238/7417) following the latex->dvips->ps2pdf sequence but in the very first stage (latex compilation) I got the error message

```
!keyval: showgrid undefined
\KV@err #1->\errmessage {keyval: #1}
```

I am using an updated MikTeX 2.9 installation on Windows XP. Anyone could possibly help on this issue? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: I edited the link to point directly to the answer (each answer has its own link), because the display order may change (in fact in my browser it's the second answer right now).