# Include political map in beamer-presentation and emphasize one country

Tags: beamer, graphics

Following [Political Map in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13220/political-map-in-latex) I want to include a "political" map of Europe and/or Germany in a beamer-class presentation.

I particularly like [this SVG map from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LocationKosovo.svg). Is it possible to modify it, so it emphasizes for example Germany?

The target should look somewhat like this (Germany emphasized in red, all other countries in grey). If the world map could be optional that would be even better.

[image: goal example]

Comment: the map you linked at wikipedia is an SVG file, you should try and open it with an svg editor like [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) and see whether you can select Germany and change the color. Then export as pdf and include as any other image.

Comment: I tried using the Map linked in the proposed example above: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:World_Map_Blank.svg I cannot select any country using Inkscape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easier way would be to have several images with different countries selected, i.e.: one image with Germany painted in red, another image with Spain painted in red and so on.

Since all images have the same size, something like this:

```
\only<1>{\includegraphics{Germany.png}}
\only<2>{\includegraphics{Spain.png}}
\only<3>{\includegraphics{Portugal.png}}
```

will give the ilusion that you have deselect Germany and selected Spain, and then deselected Spain and selected Portugal. It also looks clearer

Comment: Sorry, I can't make sense of your answer - please elaborate what this would accomplish? I want to emphasize on country (no animation requiered).

Comment: @FLW: Nico's answers is the simplest approach coming also in my mind. You want to select a country, right? Then if you have at least two images, one without any selection, the second one with Germany selected, then using an overlay allows to first display the basic map and in the next step the map with Germany selected. Nico used more countries, but it's the same thing.

Comment: There are 2 questions: how to accomplish something in LaTeX and how to get an image with Germany selected. The first question is already answered.

Comment: OK I understand.

Comment: Sorry, I posted my comment too soon. As to the second question, I've downloaded [link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:World_Map_Blank.svg) and could edited with corel draw. Take into account that it has grouped objects.